# Print (1) Array of Checked Values to the Console when Submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've created a function that stores checked values into the `Arr` array. I'm trying to log all the checked values into an array and print it to the console when the "View Results" button is clicked. It's working, however it prints the array multiple times, rather than just once. Consequently, when I display this result into HTML text it repeats several times on the screen. Is there any way of printing the result once when the button is clicked?

```js
const list = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".form"));
const Arr = [];
const submitBtn = document.querySelector('.submit-button');

function check(e) {
  // a) When checked display result in array
  if (e.target.checked) {
    Arr.push(`${e.target.value}`);


    // b) When unchecked remove result from array
  } else if (!e.target.checked) {
    let index = Arr.indexOf(e.target.value);
    if (index != -1) {
      Arr.splice(index, 1)
    }
  }
  submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(Arr);
  })
}

list.forEach(function(listItems) {
  listItems.addEventListener('change', check)
})
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <p> <u> Once you've checked the values below, check console to see value </u> </p>
  <br>
  <div class="list-items">

    <input type="checkbox" value="Item-1">Item-1
    <br>

    <input type="checkbox" value="Item-2">Item-2
    <br>

    <input type="checkbox" value="Item-3">Item-3
    <br>

    <input type="checkbox" value="Item-4">Item-4
    <br>

    <input type="checkbox" value="Item-5">Item-5
    <br>

    <input type="checkbox" value="Item-6">Item-6
    <br>

    <input type="checkbox" value="Item-7">Item-7
  </div>

  <div class="form submit">
    <h3 class="submit-message">Please click "View Results" to see your checked values in the console.
      <br>
      <button class="submit-button"><a href="#">View Results</a></button>
    </h3>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `submitBtn.addEventListener` outside the `check` method. Every time the form is changed new event listener is being added due to which you are seeing multiple time prints.

```js
const list = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".form"));
const Arr = [];
const submitBtn = document.querySelector('.submit-button');

function check(e) {
  // a) When checked display result in array
  if (e.target.checked) {
    Arr.push(`${e.target.value}`);


    // b) When unchecked remove result from array
  } else if (!e.target.checked) {
    let index = Arr.indexOf(e.target.value);
    if (index != -1) {
      Arr.splice(index, 1)
    }
  }
}
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function() { // move this outside
    console.log(Arr);
});

list.forEach(function(listItems) {
  listItems.addEventListener('change', check)
})
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <p> <u> Once you've checked the values below, check console to see value </u> </p>
  <br>
  <div class="list-items">

    <input type="checkbox" value="Item-1">Item-1
    <br>

    <input type="checkbox" value="Item-2">Item-2
    <br>

    <input type="checkbox" value="Item-3">Item-3
    <br>

    <input type="checkbox" value="Item-4">Item-4
    <br>

    <input type="checkbox" value="Item-5">Item-5
    <br>

    <input type="checkbox" value="Item-6">Item-6
    <br>

    <input type="checkbox" value="Item-7">Item-7
  </div>

  <div class="form submit">
    <h3 class="submit-message">Please click "View Results" to see your checked values in the console.
      <br>
      <button class="submit-button"><a href="#">View Results</a></button>
    </h3>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you @deepakchethan. So what I understand is that `submitBtn` needs to exist outside of the check function scope in order to not repeat due to the function values consistently changing?

Comment: Yes @WeeklyButterfly34, right now since its inside the function every time it is invoked we are adding a new click event listener.